# Initialize DIR() function with HTTP server

Tags: vba

Hi the following line does not work if I run it after a PC reboot:

```
Filename = Dir("\\epocal-db-01\qa\docs\shared documents\17000001-*.xlsx")
```

but it does if I run this line first:

```
Set Wk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="http://epocal-db-01/qa/docs/Shared Documents/17000001-00.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0)
```

It sounds like a network mapping issue in my PC. Can I map the Http server without using the (slow) open method? Do I need to declare a library?
Thanks!

Comment: do you get an error message?